# openapi-generator-maven-plugin no delegate pattern for jax-rs?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, openapi-generator

I am doing a migration project . The current project is implemented as a spring boot project.
And the api is generated with "openapi-generator-maven-plugin" . So far so good.

Now I got the task to migrate from Spring to Jakarta . Ideally I was planning to take over most of the code.

But first there seems to be no implementation for jakarta in openapi-generator-maven-plugin . There seems only to be a java ee 8 implementation . But ok wouldn't be to bad . I just run a search and replace in my notepad++ which replaces all javax with jakarta .

But what is worse it seems the option "delegatePattern" seems not to be available for java EE ?
I mean java EE also has dependency injection so DelegateImpl could easily be injected.
How come as far as I know there is this option for Delegate missing ?